# JAXB Xml Shema for xml with multiple Elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a xml shema to marshal and unmarshal xml.

Now my problem:

I get xml files with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <request  id="2">
   <body>
    <adress type="pfad">
     exsample/Barcode02
    </adress>
    <adress type="name">
     Barcode02
    </adress>
    <adress type="nummer">
     105
    </adress>
 </body>
</request>
```

There are multiple adress atrributes, each differs in the type.

How do I have to setup my shema, so it will accept xml files like this.
At the moment it looks like the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="eventType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="bt:bodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="pdt:adress" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Thanks in advance

Dimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to write a schema for modeling your XML files.
So the given schema is merely an example.
It defines and references several named `complexType`s,
  thus avoiding an overly deep nested structure.
The `maxOccurs="unbounded"` is needed so that
  a `<body>` can contain multiple `<adress>` elements.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="request" type="request" />

  <xs:complexType name="request">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="body" type="body" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="body">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="adress" type="adress" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="adress">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```